# iOS - Extra White Space in iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm beginning my first project on the newest version of Xcode (6). I have a UIImageView with my background on my default scene, and, in the past using this method, the Simulator would show the image taking up the entire screen. Now, it displays like this:

[image: screenshot of whitespace]

There is vertical and horizontal whitespace (which, like I said, isn't there in a project I made in Xcode 5). The image is in my Images.xcassets and has an @2x version. What is the cause/fix for this?

Comment: What size is your image?

Comment: 768x1024. The @2x version is 1536x2048.

Comment: How are you creating the image view?

Comment: Via Interface Builder (I imagine the problem has to do with this). I've resized it to the size of the entire view, and the view appears to be completely covered in the IB, even though the whitespace is still there in Simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use auto layout to add horizontal and vertical constraints to the edge of the view:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aa0fez2wsoexibu/qq.png?dl=0